# Why aren't I getting the correct Len of the number of elements in a key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def wordPattern(pattern, str):
    """
    :type pattern: str
    :type str: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    list_pattern = list()
    list_str = list()
    for letter in pattern:
        list_pattern.append(letter)
    for word in str.split():
        list_str.append(word)

    new_dict = {}
    c = 0

    for letter in list_pattern:
        if letter not in new_dict:
            new_dict[letter] = ''
        if list_str[c] not in new_dict[letter]:
            new_dict[letter] = list_str[c]
        c = c + 1

    for key in new_dict:
        if len(new_dict[key]) != 1:
            print (len(new_dict[key]))
            print (new_dict[key])
            print ('false')

    print ('true')
    print(new_dict)

wordPattern("abba","dog cat cat dog")
```

Question I'm trying to solve is :
Given a pattern and a string str, find if str follows the same pattern.

Here follow means a full match, such that there is a bijection between a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in str.

Examples:

pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return true.

pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat fish" should return false.

pattern = "aaaa", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return false.

pattern = "abba", str = "dog dog dog dog" should return false.

Notes:

You may assume pattern contains only lowercase letters, and str contains lowercase letters separated by a single space.

The outcome:

```
3
dog
false
3
cat
false
true
{'a': 'dog', 'b': 'cat'}
```

I can't understand why I'm getting 3 as Len(list_name[key_name]) while it's visibly 1? Kindly note that I understand there's probably better ways etc but I'm starting to learn and I want to understand my mistake.

Comment: You are getting the length of the string, and "dog" and "cat" happen to both be 3 characters long.

Comment: oh ok and how can I adjust to get the number of elements per key.

Comment: By making sure you are actually working with a list. ``new_dict[letter] = ''`` and ``new_dict[letter] = list_str[c]`` both assign a string to the dictionary item. You could just ``print (new_dict)`` to see what your dict looks like.

Comment: I have printed new_dict as can be seen from my code and the output but it looks like a dict for me, and any suggested adjustments.

Comment: It is a dict where the value of each key is a string. You should add the expected ouput to the question, because if you are talking about "elements per key" then the value should probably a list, and then your dict *could* like like this: ``{'a': ['dog'], 'b': ['cat']}``, in which case the "length of the dict item value" would be ``1`` (because it's a list with 1 item).

Comment: I fixed my own answer after this new_dict[letter] = [] andnew_dict[letter].append(list_str[c]) thanks for the explanation:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic can be reduced to a couple of lines:

```
def wordPattern(pattern, mystr):
    d = dict(zip(pattern, mystr.split()))   
    return mystr.split() == list(map(d.get, pattern))

wordPattern("abba","dog cat cat dog")  # True
```

**Explanation**

- Create a dictionary mapping letters to words via `zip`.
- Test if your list of words align to a list generated from mapping letters via your dictionary.

**Update**

You can easily deal with edge cases via an `if` statement:

```
def wordPattern(pattern, mystr):
    d = dict(zip(pattern, mystr.split()))

    if sorted(d.values()) != sorted(set(d.values())):
        return False

    return mystr.split() == list(map(d.get, pattern))

wordPattern("abba","dog dog dog dog")  # False
```

Comment: I really think I'll need some time to reach that level of concise answers, I don't even understand what zip and map are but I'll look it up and check how it weight efficiency wise against my way, thanks :)

Comment: Sure. Explaining each built-in function is beyond the scope of your question, but I suggest you read the python documentation to improve your understanding. Good luck!

Comment: I got a wrong answer when wodPattern("abba","dog dog dog dog") wheretrue
{'a': ['dog'], 'b': ['dog']}, basically it's supposed to be false, any idea how to adjust my code to solve such cases

Comment: if list_str[c] not in new_dict[letter] and list_str[c] not in new_dict.values() didn't work